Are we able to use near-indexer-framework with current Existing Validator Node?
If i have a validator node is running, are we possible to use near-indexer-frameowork without init a new full Node and based on current validator node to index the data? Currently saw it in Nearcore repo is init a new indexer with init a new Node

The author and maintainer of the near-indexer-framework is here.
While it is theoretically possible from the code point of view, I strongly advise against it. The 'near-indexer-framework' was specifically designed to work on a non-validator node, and using it on a validator node will introduce additional overhead that could impact your validation duty.
Two (or more) separate nearcore nodes cannot use the same data without corrupting it, so if you want to proceed with the idea, you'll have to turn your validator into an indexer-validator and can break everything on your side.
Please, use a different nearcore setup for indexing purposes.

thanks a lot ! appreciate your quick replied !
